# Uninstalling a Homebrew formula deleted the entire /usr/local directory

Tags: mac, macos, homebrew

I tried to uninstall Homebrew installed MySQL by running:

`brew uninstall mysql`

However, this command removed the whole `/usr/local` directory. I checked Trash, but unable to locate it.

Is there a way to get it back?

Comment: Uh... Are you sure? Was this a custom formula or something? That definitely shouldn't have happened if your brew was fubar from too many changes (to brew itself or the mysql formula)

Comment: `sudo ls /usr/local` outputs nothing?

Comment: @user3052786 yeah, its weird. I installed mysql, checked the version which was not for my likinng, did brew uninstall mysql local removed along with mysql. mysql was intalled inside this folder

Comment: @user3052786, I reinstall sierra. local just have bin folder now